# append variables to a pickle file and read them

Tags: python, append, pickle

I'm trying to append several variables to a pickle file to read them later. But it doesn't work as I expected. I would expect that at the end of this script c='A' and d='B' but instead it thows me an error. Could you please explain me why and how to get what I want? Many thanks

```
import pickle

filename = 'test.pkl'
a = 'A'
b = 'B'
with open(filename, 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(a, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open(filename, 'ab') as handle:
    pickle.dump(b, handle)

with open(filename, 'rb') as filehandle:
    c,d  = pickle.load(filehandle)
```

Answer (score 0):

After running your code, I got `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`.

If you run `help(pickle.load)`, it will tell you that it only loads objects from the file. If you have multiple objects in the file, you have to call `pickle.load` multiple times to read the objects sequentially.

Your issue is basically you stored them as 2 separate objects but are attempting to read them as a single tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `pickle.load(filehandle)` only selects the first object. The most common way to solve this problem is to use a tuple or list. So basically how this works is that you pickle one object, which can be the first object, and then decompose it later. So you would  do this:

```
import pickle

filename = 'test.pkl'
a = 'A'
b = 'B'
List = (a,b)

with open(filename, 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(List, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open(filename, 'rb') as filehandle:
    c,d  = pickle.load(filehandle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Every `load` must corresponds to a single `dump` in the pickling code. You can't have a `load` that gets the values from two separate `dump` calls, they need to match

So you can *either*:

1. `load` twice to match two `dump` calls:

   ```
   # dump code unchanged

   with open(filename, 'rb') as filehandle:
       c = pickle.load(filehandle)   # Load first object
       d = pickle.load(filehandle)   # Load second object
   ```
2. `dump` as a single object so it can be `load`ed as a single object:

   ```
   with open(filename, 'wb') as handle:
       # dump a simple anonymous tuple of both objects
       pickle.dump((a, b), handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

   # Original load code unchanged
   ```

Since you clearly know exactly how many objects must be dumped, either solution works; I'd choose #2 in most cases, unless the two objects are computed in wildly different places in the code and not preserved, requiring the first object to be serialized and discarded before the second exists.